# Issue on mysql while copy table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have 3 tables. Calls: result, project, save_result.

```
mysql_query('insert_into project (user_id, project_id)
    VALUES('.$_SESSION['id'].', $_POST['pr_id'])
    ');

$last_id=mysql_insert_id();
```

Now, I want to copy the table `result` (user_id, status_id) to another table 
`save_result` (project_id, user_id, status_id)

Using this method on below misses project_id. How can I insert $last_id to row `project_id`?

```
  mysql_query(
    'INSERT INTO
      save_result (project_id, user_id, status_id)
    SELECT
      * 
    FROM
      result
    WHERE
      user_id='.$_SESSION['id'].'
      ');
```

I do not want use mysql_fetch_array. Also do not want update this table again inserting project_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO
  save_result (project_id, user_id, status_id)
SELECT
  '". $last_id ."' as project_id, * 
FROM
  result
WHERE
  user_id='.$_SESSION['id'].'
  ');
```

just pass $lastId as constant to query as first value [since projectid is first value in field list]...

Comment: oohhh Yeah, I was knowing this way actually )) THANK YOU